# What are the resource requirements (RAM, flash) of the latest Nordic Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) stack?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, nrf51822, nordic

I want to understand how much RAM and flash I have available for my own program memory and program space after I incorporate the overhead of Bluetooth communication when using an nRF51822.

https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=/struct_nrf51/struct/s110.html

Comment: it's still called BLE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this writing (Sept 2014), the S110 v7 softdevice uses 88 kB flash and 8 kB of static RAM for S110 leaving 168 kB of flash and 8 kB of RAM for the application (for the 256k chip). Also note that S110 v7 can use over 1.5 kB of stack, so you must make sure that your stack is big enough to accomodate both this and your application's requirement.

Lastly, when you use the S110, it also restricts many of the Programmable Peripheral Interconnect (PPI) channels, leaving on 8 channels free for the application code. This restricts how you implemet peripherals such as PWM and I2C.

[image]

[image]

Read the latest [SoftDevice Specification (currently v1.3)](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/S110_SDS_v1.3.pdf)

Comment: can you post a direct link to the nordic site (e.g. somewhere more reputable?)

Comment: you will have to make an account with nordic to see this document

Comment: @tarabyte, I've updated the link to point to the correct documention on the Nordic site directly.

Comment: @hassan789, no Nordic account is needed (anymore?) to view this document